# How to I parse problematic strings

Tags: python, parsing

I'm working on a Scratch - Python handler and basically could do with the help of a parsing guru :)

I'm working on trying to handle input that is not quite correct (my Scratch programmers can be as young as 7 so my hander should receive strings like this

```
"motor1" "12.5" "motor2" 80 "sonar8" "Pin11On"
```

but they can easily end up like this when Scratch has wrapped extra " around variable/name values with spaces in them

```
"motor 1" "12.345 " "motor2" 80 "sonar 8" "Pin 11 On"
```

What I'm looking for is code to take above and return a new string

```
motor1 12.345 motor2 80 sonar8 Pin11On
```

Any suggestions greatly received :)

Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [52]: text = '"motor 1" "12.345 " "motor2" 80 "sonar 8" "Pin 11 On"'

In [53]: import shlex

In [54]: shlex.split(text)
Out[54]: ['motor 1', '12.345 ', 'motor2', '80', 'sonar 8', 'Pin 11 On']

In [55]: [item.replace(' ','') for item in shlex.split(text)]
Out[55]: ['motor1', '12.345', 'motor2', '80', 'sonar8', 'Pin11On']

In [56]: ' '.join([item.replace(' ','') for item in shlex.split(text)])
Out[56]: 'motor1 12.345 motor2 80 sonar8 Pin11On'
```